# My UIView doesn't show up as I try to set constraints relative to safe area programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, safearealayoutguide

I have a StackContainerView inside my main view controller called TodayPicksViewController. I am trying to programmatically set the StackContainerView to fill up the whole view controller side to side, with around 50 from top and bottom (just like a Tinder card).

However, as I try to implement constraints relative to safe area as follows(as other answers on StackOverflow suggest), turned out the StackContainerView doesn't show up at all. I don't know where the problem is.

Please advice.

Code of my main view controller, TodayPicksViewController:

```
class TodayPicksViewController: UIViewController  {
        
    //MARK: - Properties
    var viewModelData = [CardsDataModel(bgColor: UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.81, blue:0.46, alpha:1.0), text: "Hamburger", image: "hamburger"),
                         CardsDataModel(bgColor: UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.64, blue:0.96, alpha:1.0), text: "Puppy", image: "puppy"),
                         CardsDataModel(bgColor: UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.63, blue:0.49, alpha:1.0), text: "Poop", image: "poop"),
                         CardsDataModel(bgColor: UIColor(red:0.69, green:0.52, blue:0.38, alpha:1.0), text: "Panda", image: "panda"),
                         CardsDataModel(bgColor: UIColor(red:0.90, green:0.99, blue:0.97, alpha:1.0), text: "Subway", image: "subway"),
                         CardsDataModel(bgColor: UIColor(red:0.83, green:0.82, blue:0.69, alpha:1.0), text: "Robot", image: "robot")]
    
    var stackContainer : StackContainerView!
    
    private let spinner = JGProgressHUD(style: .dark)

    private var users = [[String: String]]()

    private var results = [SearchResult]()
    
    private var hasFetched = false

    var divisor: CGFloat!
    
    private let noResultsLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.isHidden = true
        label.text = "No Results"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .green
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 21, weight: .medium)
        return label
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        stackContainer = StackContainerView()
        view.addSubview(stackContainer)
        stackContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(noResultsLabel)
        configureStackContainer()
        stackContainer.dataSource = self

    }
    
    @IBAction func panMatch(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let match = sender.view!
        let point = sender.translation(in: view)
        let xFromCenter = match.center.x - view.center.x
        print(xFromCenter)
        
        match.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + point.x, y: view.center.y + point.y)
        
        match.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: xFromCenter/divisor)
       
        
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            
            if match.center.x < 75 {
                // Move off to the left side
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    match.center = CGPoint(x: match.center.x - 200, y: match.center.y + 75)
                    match.alpha = 0
                })
                return
            } else if match.center.x > (view.frame.width - 75) {
                // Move off to the right side
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    match.center = CGPoint(x: match.center.x + 200, y: match.center.y + 75)
                    match.alpha = 0
                })
                return
            }
//            resetCard()
            
        }
    }
    
    private var loginObserver: NSObjectProtocol?
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        validateAuth()
    }
    
    private func validateAuth() {
        if FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
            let vc = SignInViewController()
            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            present(nav, animated: false)
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func pageControlDidChange(_ sender: UIPageControl) {
        let current = sender.currentPage
        //        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(current) * view.frame.size.width,
        //                                            y: 70), animated: true)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }
    
    //MARK: - Configurations
    func configureStackContainer() {
        stackContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
        
        //        stackContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        //        stackContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
        stackContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }


    func updateUI() {
        if results.isEmpty {
            noResultsLabel.isHidden = false
        }
        else {
            noResultsLabel.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    
    func calcAge(birthday: Date) -> Int {
        let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
        dateFormater.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
//        let birthdayDate = dateFormater.date(from: birthday)
        let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
        let now = Date()
        let calcAge = calendar.components(.year, from: birthday, to: now, options: [])
        let age = calcAge.year
        return age!
    }

extension TodayPicksViewController : SwipeCardsDataSource {

    func numberOfCardsToShow() -> Int {
        return viewModelData.count
    }
    
    func card(at index: Int) -> SwipeCardView {
        let card = SwipeCardView()
        card.dataSource = viewModelData[index]
        return card
    }
    
    func emptyView() -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
    

}
```

Probably doesn't matter, but here is my code for the StackContainerView:

```
class StackContainerView: UIView, SwipeCardsDelegate {

    //MARK: - Properties
    var numberOfCardsToShow: Int = 0
    var cardsToBeVisible: Int = 3
    var cardViews : [SwipeCardView] = []
    var remainingcards: Int = 0
    
    let horizontalInset: CGFloat = 10.0
    let verticalInset: CGFloat = 10.0
    
    var visibleCards: [SwipeCardView] {
        return subviews as? [SwipeCardView] ?? []
    }
    var dataSource: SwipeCardsDataSource? {
        didSet {
            reloadData()
        }
    }
    //MARK: - Init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    
    func reloadData() {
        removeAllCardViews()
        guard let datasource = dataSource else { return }
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        numberOfCardsToShow = datasource.numberOfCardsToShow()
        remainingcards = numberOfCardsToShow
        
        for i in 0..<min(numberOfCardsToShow,cardsToBeVisible) {
            addCardView(cardView: datasource.card(at: i), atIndex: i )
            
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Configurations

    private func addCardView(cardView: SwipeCardView, atIndex index: Int) {
        cardView.delegate = self
        addCardFrame(index: index, cardView: cardView)
        cardViews.append(cardView)
        insertSubview(cardView, at: 0)
        remainingcards -= 1
    }
    
    func addCardFrame(index: Int, cardView: SwipeCardView) {
        var cardViewFrame = bounds
        let horizontalInset = (CGFloat(index) * self.horizontalInset)
        let verticalInset = CGFloat(index) * self.verticalInset
        
        cardViewFrame.size.width -= 2 * horizontalInset
        cardViewFrame.origin.x += horizontalInset
        cardViewFrame.origin.y += verticalInset
        
        cardView.frame = cardViewFrame
    }
    
    private func removeAllCardViews() {
        for cardView in visibleCards {
            cardView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        cardViews = []
    }
    
    func swipeDidEnd(on view: SwipeCardView) {
        guard let datasource = dataSource else { return }
        view.removeFromSuperview()

        if remainingcards > 0 {
            let newIndex = datasource.numberOfCardsToShow() - remainingcards
            addCardView(cardView: datasource.card(at: newIndex), atIndex: 2)
            for (cardIndex, cardView) in visibleCards.reversed().enumerated() {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                cardView.center = self.center
                  self.addCardFrame(index: cardIndex, cardView: cardView)
                    self.layoutIfNeeded()
                })
            }

        }else {
            for (cardIndex, cardView) in visibleCards.reversed().enumerated() {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    cardView.center = self.center
                    self.addCardFrame(index: cardIndex, cardView: cardView)
                    self.layoutIfNeeded()
                })
            }
        }
    }
    

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this line in `viewDidLoad`?... `view = UIView()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the apple developer doc for `loadView()`, they said **"The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property."** This might be the cause of the problem. I would recommend you to perform the view set up operations in viewDidLoad or other proper lifecycle methods. Based on my understanding, this line `view = UIView()` isn't necessary. In your `configureStackContainer()` func, you set the centerX and centerY anchor and then set the top, leading, trailing, bottom anchor again. This may also raise the constraint conflicts. I think you don't need to specify centerX and centerY anchor if you want to constraint with top, leading, trailing and bottom and vice versa. I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I moved all the code in the original `loadView()` to `viewDidLoad()` and now the UIView shows up and expand to full screen! However, only the top card now has the lower bar; the rest have only the image occupying the full card.

Comment: I think you should debug with Xcode UI debugger. It'll show you how it lay things out and constraints and it's easier to find out what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even know its existence. BTW, I have a new question. If you have time, please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67217136/abnormal-behaviour-when-implementing-like-and-nope-animations-at-the-corner